# C# Program stops responding after second WebClient.DownloadString()

Tags: c#, web-services, webclient, downloadstring

I am working on a program for proof of concept that does a webrequest using `WebClient.DownloadString("http://website/members/login.php?user=" + textBox1.Text + "&pass=" + textBox2.Text);`
to get the boolean value of wether or not the user is a valid login and then if it is it gives a success notification if it isn't ten it gives a fail notification.

The problem is when i press the button to try and login the first time it works fine but when i press it again the second tine the program freezes and gets stuck at the Webclient.download string.

If anyone can spot and tell me whats wrong that would be great. I am providing the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static WebClient webclient = new WebClient();

        HttpWebResponse wResp;
        WebRequest wReq;
        bool isConnected = false;
        private String Session = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Boolean checkUser(String username, String password)
        {
                String login = `webclient.DownloadString("http://connorbp.info/members/auth.php?user=" + textBox1.Text + "&pass=" + textBox2.Text);`
                Boolean bLogin = Boolean.Parse(login);
                if (bLogin)
                {
                    Session = username + "-" + password;
                }
                return bLogin;
        }

        public int CanConnect(string dUrl)
        {
            wReq = WebRequest.Create(dUrl);
            int cnt = Connect();
            return cnt;
        }

        private int Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                wResp = (HttpWebResponse)wReq.GetResponse();
                isConnected = true;
                return 1;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int init = CanConnect("http://connorbp.info/members/auth.php");
            if (init == 0)
            {
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(200, "CBP Login", "Failed to connect to server! Try again later.", ToolTipIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                if(checkUser(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text))
                {
                    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(20, "CBP Login", "Logged In!", ToolTipIcon.Info);
                }
                else
                {
                    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(20, "CBP Login", "Invalid Username/Password!", ToolTipIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(20, "CBP Login", "for more cool things go to http://connorbp.info", ToolTipIcon.Info);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to be closing your `WebRequest` during the `Connect` method. Since this is a member variable I would try disposing of that properly first.

Comment: I finally figured it out! i was reading this wrong and it was the response in the Connect method. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not closing the response.

The second call is trying to open something that is already open, therefore it hangs.

Comment: i will try this, i was thinking somthing along the lines of this but was not sure :)

Comment: i can't seem to find how to close the response anywhere though. everywhere i look the code just does the downloadstring then exits (console application)